# Traduction de « equating them »

Tags: traduction, anglais, mathématiques, science

> Answer each question yes or no. Must two quantities have the same dimensions (a) if you are adding them? (b) If you are multiplying them? (c) If you are subtracting them? (d) If you are dividing them? (e) **If you are equating them**?

Je me demande comment dire en français *if you are equating them*. Par exemple, est-ce que *si vous les mettez sur un pied d'égalité* est correct ? et est-ce courant ?

> Répondre à chaque question par Vrai ou par Faux. Deux quantités doivent-elles avoir les mêmes dimensions (a) Si vous les ajoutez ? (b) Si vous les multipliez ?  (c) Si vous les soustrayez ? (d) Si vous les divisez ? (e) **Si vous les mettez sur un pied d'égalité** ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Les mettre sur un pied d'égalité* serait un faux-sens ici, car cela implique une égalité au regard d'un jugement subjectif, et non pas une égalité numérique.

Je traduirais, selon le contexte:

> **Si vous en postulez l'égalité?** (if you assert that they are equal)
>
> **Si vous en testez l'égalité?** (if you assert whether they are equal)

Answer (score 2):

« To equate terms » signifie seulement écrire une équation qui aura pour membre de droite l'un des deux termes et pour membre de gauche, l'autre.

Pour exprimer cela on peut dire « écrire l'égalité qui a pour membres les deux termes ».

On peut aussi dire « mettre les deux termes en équation ». Mais c'est moins spécifique ; par exemple on trouve l'exemple suivant dans le reverso ;

> L'équation (D) représente la relation de distance étalonnée et est utilisée pour mettre en équation la vitesse de crête des particules,  le poids de la charge et la distance.

On ne dit jamais en mathématiques « mettre sur un pied d'égalité » pour les équations ; c'est une expression qui concerne une égalité dans le domaines des valeurs humaines par exemple et jamais  dans le domaine de la stricte égalité logique de Leibniz.

Comment: Je ne veux pas critiquer la langue française mais on a besoin 10 mots pour interpréter 5 mots d'anglais :-)! Je te remercie encore une fois.

Comment: @dimitris Une bonne langue ne devrait pas avoir peur de la critique…

Comment: C'est bon:-)! Je vais l'utiliser comme dicton:-)!

Comment: @dimitris Je fais peut être trop vite d'une langue un être pensant avec des sentiments…

Answer (score 1):

#### Traduction du terme « equating them » dans l'énoncé ci-dessous

> *Answer each question yes or no*. Must two quantities have the same dimensions, if you are...
>
> 1. adding
> 2. multiplying
> 3. dividing
> 4. equating
>
> ... them?

Voici la réponse d'un collègue francophone :

> Deux quantités doivent-elles avoir les mêmes dimensions...
>
> 1. si vous les additionnez ?
> 2. si vous les multipliez ?
> 3. si vous les soustrayez ?
> 4. **si vous les égalisez** ?

Comment: @Fólkvangr : Merci pour avoir édité la réponse.

Answer (score 1):

> Si vous les comparez.

**Comparer** peut revêtir le sens:

> Mettre en parallèle, présenter comme semblable.

As in

> Don’t make the mistake of equating high test scores and intelligence.
>
> Ne faites pas l'erreur de comparer des hauts scores aux tests à l'intelligence.

I wouldn't say **égaliser** (and I do think it's wrong) for **equate** means

> to consider something to be the same as something else

whereas **égaliser** means

> make two things equal

So, in other words:

> si vous les considérez comme égaux

Comment: Effectivement, "pour être comparable" irait beaucoup mieux.

Comment: Mais de la même façon, on peut dire "pour être additionable" etc.